# Problema con CheckBox y SQLite en Android Studio

Tags: android, sqlite, checkbox

resulta que tengo esta clase en la que guardo la información de, entre otras cosas, 4 Checkboxes en mi Base de Datos SQLite, pero no importa si los Checkbox están seleccionados o no, siempre me carga "No" en mi base de datos.

Para que entiendan mejor a lo que me refiero, les comparto la clase donde realizo lo mencionado:

```
public class Dia extends AppCompatActivity {

private String day, reserva;
EditText etComentario;
Button bnGuardarC, bnSalirC;
TextView tvNumDia;
CheckBox cbBaniar, cbPasear, cbCortar, cbJugar;
RadioGroup rgTurno;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dia);

    reserva = getIntent().getStringExtra("reserva");

    rgTurno = findViewById(R.id.rgTurno);
    bnGuardarC = findViewById(R.id.bnGuardarC);
    bnSalirC = findViewById(R.id.bnSalirC);
    tvNumDia = findViewById(R.id.tvNumeroDia);
    cbBaniar = findViewById(R.id.cbBaniar);
    cbPasear = findViewById(R.id.cbPasear);
    cbCortar = findViewById(R.id.cbCortar);
    cbJugar = findViewById(R.id.cbJugar);
    etComentario = findViewById(R.id.etComentario);

    day = getIntent().getStringExtra("numdia");

    final String baniar, pasear, cortar, jugar;

    if(cbBaniar.isChecked()){
        baniar="Si";
    }else{
        baniar="No";
    }

    if(cbPasear.isChecked()){
        pasear="Si";
    }else{
        pasear="No";
    }

    if(cbCortar.isChecked()){
        cortar="Si";
    }else{
        cortar="No";
    }

    if(cbJugar.isChecked()){
        jugar="Si";
    }else{
        jugar="No";
    }

    TextView tvDia = findViewById(R.id.tvNumeroDia);
    tvDia.setText(day);

    final BaseDeDatos tablaCuidados = new BaseDeDatos(getApplicationContext());

    bnGuardarC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tablaCuidados.insertarCuidado(null, "#1111", day, rgTurno.getCheckedRadioButtonId(), baniar, pasear,
                    cortar, jugar, etComentario.getText().toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "¡Cuidado guardado con éxito!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


}
```

}

Como podrán observar, a los Checkbox los paso por un If, y si .isChecked == true, debería guardarme "Si" en su variable, caso contrario debería guardarme "No".
La app corre lo más bien, sólo que cuando voy a ver lo que se guardó en mi base de datos, los campos de la tabla que hacen referencia a los Checkbox aparecen cargados todos en "No", o sea como si el .isChecked no estuviera funcionando. 
Tal vez no lo estoy utilizando de la manera correcta, me podrían ayudar?

Les dejo una captura abajo con los resultados de mi base de datos y los campos de los checkboxes marcados en amarillo:

[image: Esta es una captura con los 4 campos marcados en amarillo donde se ve lo que menciono]

Gracias!

Comment: Primero sacale el final a los Strings baniar, pasear, cortar, jugar, ya que cuando se llama a onCreate() los checkbox estan deseleccionados, por ende todas estas variables toman el valor de no(...isChecked() dan false todas) y al ser final, si usted modifica el checkbox no importa ya que la variable definida como final cuando toma valor, no cambia su valor en toda la ejecucion.
Y segundo, debes comprobar los estados de los checkbox cuando haces click en el boton, no cuando se crea la activity, entonces esos if de comprobacion deberian estar dentro del clickListener y antes de la parte del codi

Comment: Sos un genio! problema solucionado. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Marcala como respuesta  asi si alguien tiene un problema parecido ya se da cuenta que esta solucionado! de nada

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Primero sacale el final a los Strings baniar, pasear, cortar, jugar, ya que cuando se llama a onCreate() los checkbox estan deseleccionados, por ende todas estas variables toman el valor de no(...isChecked() dan false todas) y al ser final, si usted modifica el checkbox no importa ya que la variable definida como final cuando toma valor, no cambia su valor en toda la ejecucion.
Y segundo, debes comprobar los estados de los checkbox cuando haces click en el boton, no cuando se crea la activity, entonces esos if de comprobacion deberian estar dentro del clickListener y antes de la parte del codigo donde guardas la base de datos!

Comment: Sos un genio! problema solucionado. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Marcala como respuesta  asi si alguien tiene un problema parecido ya se da cuenta que esta solucionado! de nada